# sort ruby hash when using json

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, hash

I have a Ruby hash which I'm converting `to_json` and passing to a view. JavaScript then parses the JSON (`JSON.parse`) and iterates it, spewing out the key, value pairs. How do I sort the hash so that my key/value pairs are ordered alphabetically by key? This can be done before passing to the view or in JavaScript as long as the final result is an ordered list of key/values. `hash.sort` does not work, neither does `hash.to_a.sort`... If I do this, I find that I cannot iterate properly and get both key and value.

`for (key in myHash) {alert(key); alert(myHash[key]); }` doesn't work once sort is applied.

Comment: In ruby 1.8, hashes are not ordered. In ruby 1.9.2, they are ordered.  So, I would either switch to 1.9.2, or not use hashes if you need them in any sort of order.

Comment: @Jesse Wolgamott whether or not the hashes can be retrieved in order *in Ruby* is not really important, as the real issue is that they won't be sorted on the JavaScript side.

Comment: @Jesse Wolgamott, "In ruby 1.9.2, they are ordered.". No, they only remember their insertion order, but they're not ordered: `asdf = {z:26,a:1} #=> {:z=>26, :a=>1}`

Comment: Your best bet is to not worry whether Ruby orders the hash before generating the JSON. Sort the hash once the JSON has been decoded by Javascript: Extract the keys from the hash, sort them, then iterate over them grabbing the value for each key.

Comment: @Pointy: Good point, this question is much more JS than ruby. @the Tin Man: excellent distinction

Answer (score 5):

```
h = {"b"=>2, "a"=>1}

Hash[*h.sort.flatten].to_json
```

Comment: The problem is that it won't *stay* sorted when it's turned back into a JavaScript object on the far side. (Oh, that is, unless "flatten" turns it into an array instead of a key/value object ...)

Answer (score 2):

Convert the hash to an array and then sort it:

```
var arr = [];
for (var key in hash) {
  if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(hash, key))
    arr.push([key, hash[key]]);
}
arr.sort(function(h1, h2) {
  return h1[0] > h2[0] ? 1 : h1[0] < h2[0] ? -1 : 0;
});
```

Now you can iterate over "arr", and the keys will be in order.

You could also make it an array on the Ruby side, so that the JavaScript code gets a JSON array in the right order instead of a JSON object.

Answer (score 2):

```
def sort_hash(h)
  {}.tap do |h2|
    h.sort.each do |k,v|
      h2[k] = v.is_a?(Hash) ? sort_hash(v) : v
    end
  end
end
```

From: [How to convert hash to json while keeping things sorted in ruby template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733764/how-to-convert-hash-to-json-while-keeping-things-sorted-in-ruby-template)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 h = {"b"=>2, "a"=>1}
 ActiveSupport::OrderedHash[*h.sort].to_json
```

Comment: That won't work if the Javascript side doesn't maintain the hash order.

Comment: I know :-). This is an answer to user's question, i.e. how to create a Ordered Hash in rails.